# Is this code is correct to print time according to days

Tags: php, date

Please anyone check it and correct it.

```
<?php
    $dt='2017-08-30';
    $dt1 = strtotime($dt);
    $dt2 = date("l", $dt1);
    $dt3 = strtolower($dt2);
    if(($dt3 == "Monday" ))
        {
            echo "6:00-8:00";
        } 
    else if(($dt3 == "tuesday" ))
        {
            echo "8:00-10:00";
        } 
    else    if(($dt3 == "wednesday" ))
        {
             echo "10:00-12:00";
        } 
    else    if(($dt3 == "thursday" ))
        {
             echo "12:00-14:00";
        } 
    else    if(($dt3 == "friday" ))
        {
            echo "14:00-16:00";
        } 
    else    if(($dt3 == "saturday" ))
        {
            echo "14:00-16:00";
        }
    else    if(($dt3 == "sunday" ))
        {
            echo "16:00-18:00";
        }
?>
```

If

Monday print 6-8

Tuesday print 8-10

Wednesday print 10-12

Thursday print 12-14

Friday print 14-16

Saturday print 16-18

Sunday print 16-18

Comment: You should run it and let us know the results. If you are looking for a code review try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: change `"Monday"` to `"monday"` as you are comparing it with lowercase

Comment: typo on Saturday between code and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a battery of if statements, use a lookup array.  It will be easier to read and manage.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a3ab13de331e1ef1be20474c89d4a172684071d5))

```
$lookup=['Monday'=>'6:00-8:00',
         'Tueday'=>'8:00-10:00',
         'Wednesday'=>'10:00-12:00',
         'Thursday'=>'12:00-14:00',
         'Friday'=>'14:00-16:00',
         'Saturday'=>'14:00-16:00',
         'Sunday'=>'16:00-18:00'];
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')){
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');  // whatever timezone you wish
}
$day=date("l");
    //$dt='2017-08-30';
    //$day=date("l",strtotime($dt));
echo $day,' ',$lookup[$day];
```

or with `DateTime`...

```
$TZ=new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata');  // whatever timezone you wish
$now=new DateTime('NOW',$TZ);
$day=$now->format('l');
echo $day,' ',$lookup[$day];
```

Output:

```
Wednesday 10:00-12:00
```

Comment: much better answer.+1

Comment: Actually I want to change automatically according to days if today is Thursday it print 12-14 & if tomorrow is friday time will change to 14-16.

Comment: @Mr.Kumar  Good news: That's exactly what this does.  Click my Demo link, change the date to the 31st of August and see how it changes.

Comment: But i want to set one date it will change time daily without changing the date.

Comment: I think you are asking how to make today's day name dynamic. 
 See this modified demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3243ed64287359de3a7d9083a06b58a4f4535170

Comment: Yes exactly but I think output of code is incorrect today is Thursday it printed Wednesday 10:00-12:00. Instead of printing Thursday 12:00-14:00.

Comment: You will need to get your timezone settings correct.  Write something like this before calling `strtotime()` : `if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
}`

Comment: @ mickmackusa  Thanks This code works for me.

Comment: yes i know which is on top right side..