# Simple PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to learn PHP and challenged myself with this simple demo to learn how to use arrays. The challenge: display a string that will show a restaurant's daily special for the appropriate day.

Sunday = closed
Monday = Taco
Tuesday = Chicken
Wednesday = Lasagna
Thursday = Sushi
Friday = Salmon
Saturday = Steak

Example if the current day is Thursday:
***Today's special is Sushi.***

Here's the baseline I've been working from:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$day = date('l');
$days = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
$specials = array('closed','Taco','Chicken','Lasagna','Sushi','Salmon','Steak');
?>
<p>Today is <?php echo $day; ?></p>
<p>Today's Special is: <?php Cant Figure Out What Goes Here ?></p>
```

Comment: You would have to use a for loop and many if statements. I can help you.

Comment: Look up associative array   Where it's $key => $value.  Assign key as day and value as specials. Loop with a `foreach($arrayname as $key => $special) { if($day == $key)} echo $special {;`

Comment: Tip: `date('w')` and use that as the array index (`$days[date('w')]`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this code is correct to print time according to days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45973741/is-this-code-is-correct-to-print-time-according-to-days) There is no shortage of "[php] lookup array" pages on SO.  Always research and research some more before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way

```
$current_day = date('l');

//set up your array so you can grab the special based on the key (Which is the day)
$days = array(
    //key "Sunday" value "Closed"
    "Sunday" => "Closed", 
    //key "Monday" value "Taco" etc etc etc
    "Monday" => "Taco",
    "Tuesday" => "Chicken", 
    "Wednesday" => "Lasagna",
    "Thursday" => "Sushi", 
    "Friday" => "Salmon",
    "Saturday" => "Steak",
);

//check which day it is using a switch statement
switch($current_day) {
    //if it's sunday, you should display a "we are closed" message
    case "Sunday":
        $special = "Sorry, today we are closed.";
        break;
    //if its anything but sunday, access the array using the key, which happens to be a `$current_day` every time
    default:
        $special = "Todays special is: {$days[$current_day]}";

}

//echo current day
echo "<p>Today is {$current_day}</p>";

//echo $special based on the switch statement above.
echo "<p>{$special}</p>";
```

Don't get confused by my use of curly brackets, those are called complex expressions, I [just explained how they work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989331/php-mysql-incrementing-variable-name-to-loop-for-data/45989396#45989396) just a few moments ago. They are just for string concatenation. You could echo those variables the same way as you did before as well

```
<p>Today is <?php echo $current_day; ?></p>
<p><?php $special; ?></p>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I also appreciate the comments in your example to help me understand the logic so I can learn from it.

Comment: @ScottS. That's my goal!:) If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
<p>Today is <?php echo $day; ?></p>
<p>Today's Special is: <?php echo $specials[array_search($day, $days)]; ?></p>
```

array_search will get the key of the provided value($day) from $days array.

$specials[array_search($day, $days)] will get the value from $specials array.

Comment: Today is Thursday but some reason the code is displaying Sunday's special (i.e. It's closed)

Comment: Check this for results http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6ec71ce491a5faa6f90704bd4301cd760c2c307

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by iterating through the variables in the arrays. The first time of the loop, it will print `Sorry, we are closed`. The rest of the time, it will print (2nd time): `Today's special is Taco!`The `.`is used to join things up, like the `+` in other languages.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $day = date('l');
        $days = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
        $specials = array('closed','Taco','Chicken','Lasagna','Sushi','Salmon','Steak');

        for($i=0;$i<$days;$i++){
            if($days[$i] == "Monday"){

                echo $day;
                echo "Sorry we are".$specials[$i];

            }

            echo $day;
            echo "Today's special is".$specials[$i]."!"

        }

    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this solves you doubt. So what I did work, your file must be saved as `.php`